# Ansible: How to delete files starting with a specific name?

Tags: ansible

I am new to Ansible.

I have such a directory:

```
home/etc/directory/
```

Which contains the following files:

```
application.yml
application.yml_new
application.yml.12345
etc.yml
```

What I want to do is to delete/remove the files

```
application.yml_new
application.yml.12345
```

I do not want to explicitly name these files but I want to delete all files with a suffix additional to `application.yml` (since the names are slightly different depending on the application).

Now I am wondering how to do this?

I found the `file` but I am not sure if I can do this with it or can it be only done with the `shell`-module?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Q: *"**Delete all files with a suffix additional to application.yml**"*

A: Find the files first. For example, given the tree

```sh
shell> tree etc/directory
etc/directory/
├── application.yml
├── application.yml.12345
├── application.yml_new
└── etc.yml

0 directories, 4 files
```

The module [*find*](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/find_module.html) does the job

```yaml
    - find:
        paths: etc/directory
        patterns: '^application\.yml.+$'
        use_regex: true
      register: result
```

gives

```yaml
  result.files|map(attribute='path')|list:
  - etc/directory/application.yml.12345
  - etc/directory/application.yml_new
```

Iterate the list and delete the files

```yaml
    - file:
        state: absent
        path: "{{ item }}"
      loop: "{{ result.files|map(attribute='path')|list }}"
```

gives

```sh
shell> tree etc/directory
etc/directory/
├── application.yml
└── etc.yml

0 directories, 2 files
```

---

Explanation of the Python regex

```py
patterns: '^application\.yml.+$'
```

```sh
^ ............. matches the beginning of the string
application ... matches the string 'application'
\. ............ matches dot '.'; must be escaped because of dot matches any character
yml ........... matches the string 'yml'
.+ ............ matches one or more of any characters
$ ............. matches the end of the string
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to achieve this is to use the `find command` in combination with the `file module` in ansible.

Like this:

```
- name: getfiles
  shell: "find * -name 'application.yml*' ! -name application.yml"
  register: files_to_delete
  args:
    chdir: "/home/admin"

- name: delete files
  file:
    path: "/home/admin/{{item}}"
    state: absent
  with_items: "{{files_to_delete.stdout_lines}}"
```

First, we search for the files by using the find command and register the results in a variable.

Then we are able to use the stdout lines which is an array of the filenames we want to delete.

**NOTE: Because the find command also includes the `application.yml` I exclude it. As seen in the example above**

At last, we can loop over the list and delete the files.